designing spreads in print html/css
Is it possible to use print html/css to design elements which span across pages.
For example a big title going from the left page over to the right page.
Do I have to double the page width and design a spread as one page?
Then I would not be able to use the @page:right and @page:left selectors any more ...
I already searched the internet, but I could not find anything referencing this problem.
